# Xcode UI does not show the Core Data entities I have created

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Xcode Core Data UI does not show the entities I created in graph view. Why is this? How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that the 'class' view only shows 2 entities but 7 should exist? Are they on top of each other or off the edge of the canvas?

Comment: Yes 7 should exist as seen in the picture. I tried moving them around, it doesn't seem like they are on top of each other. (Unless when I try to select, it selects them all at once)

Comment: Why delete ios7 and xcode5 tags? I don't want confusion about which version I am working on.

Comment: Initially, from the description, it sounded like the question was about SQLite table, not Xcode UI. Updated your wording and tags now. Still not an iOS7 issue (or iOS at all really).

Comment: Sounds obvious, but have you already tried to move it around? Another entities can be underneath the top one.

Comment: When I click on their names from the left menu, the graphical table highlights for the ones that are in the view. But not for the ones that aren't showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph editor is quirky at the best of times.  Restarting Xcode frequently fixes the issue.  Switching from the table style to the graph style can force a redraw.  Closing the file (not the project, just the model file) and reopening it can also clear this up.

If neither of those are working then you probably have a corrupted xcshareddata file in your Xcode project.  Try removing that file (or renaming it to test) while Xcode is not running and then launch Xcode and force it to rebuild it.

Comment: this kinda fixed it, tho I am not sure what exactly, I tried everything, then started working on another class, then randomly it was fixed :v

Comment: The diagram view has been removed from the Core Data data model editor in Xcode 14.